# python loc condition on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, pandas-loc

I'm trying to use LOC with a condition to keep data in my dataframe only if four columns have same entry `(column 1 == column 2 )` and `(column 3 == column 4 )`.

My Dataframe is a result of df.concat of 2 dataframes and i am trying to keep data where data in column 1 and 3 from my first dataframe equals data in column 2 and 4 from my second dataframe.

```
df = df.loc[(df['column1'] == df['column2']) & (df['column3'] == df['column4'])]
```

i know that the columns share multiple entries but the result i get is an empty dataframe.

Any idea where i could be wrong ?

Comment: Can you please provide us with some sample data on which we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry i don't have sample data because it is from work i am doing online. The entries are movies and tv shows from both Netflix and Imdb and i have to concatenate the datafrmes in one dataframe and keep only the entries with the same title and the same release year on the original dataframes. ( column title originally from the netflix dataframe == column primaryTitle originally from the imdb dataframe , column release_year originally from the netflix dataframe == column start_year originally from the imdb dataframe)

Comment: check if you have additional spaces or case sensitivity in the columns, and first thing is run this with one or two records with sample dataset as folks above have suggested. Dont run it across the whole frame. And then once your condition is satisfied, try to flip it for a record that should fail.